# Nested runAction()

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

How safe is it to call a runAction from within a CCCallBlock?
My code is:

```
CCSprite *sprite1;
CCSprite *sprite2;

...Some sprite init stuff...

[sprite1 runAction:
    [CCSequence actions:
        [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1.0 scale:2.0],
        [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
           [sprite2 runAction:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:5.0 scale:2.0]
        }],
        [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1.0 scale:1.0],
        nil
    ]
];
```

Note that the sprite1 animation will end before the sprite2 animation fired in the CCCallBlock will end. It crashes but I don't understand why. So, is it safe to make such a call (seems not, at least doing like that)? Why? How would it be safe(r)?

Btw, having my sprite2 animation shorter than sprite1 one do not crash, so I suspect my second animation to be release somewhere but I don't enter its dealloc()...

Thx.

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: Not sure why he is getting a crash. His code that he posted doesn't compile. When I fixed that simple error and tried it in a new project, it worked just fine. I added the fix in my answer post below.

Answer (score 1):

The code you wrote doesn't compile FYI.

What you are doing works fine. I just tried it after fixing the code you posting with the compile error. Here is what I used:

```
CCSprite *sprite1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"temp.png"];
CCSprite *sprite2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"temp.png"];

[sprite1 runAction:[CCSequence actions:
    [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1.0 scale:2.0],
    [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^
    {
        [sprite2 runAction:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:5.0 scale:2.0]];
    }],
    [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1.0 scale:1.0],
    nil]
];

[self addChild:sprite1];
[self addChild:sprite2];
```

Comment: Well, I expected someone to tell me a semicolon or something like that was missing. I extracted my code and just put the relevant parts... So ok it doesn't compile, but my original code compiles. I never told it doesn't compile, I told it crashes, like yours by the way. Thanks for trying to fix my typos, but it doesn't solve my prob. For the moment I extracted the nested runAction and I call it separately, and I still wonder what goes wrong with my previous code.

Comment: Mine does not crash for me. I tried it in a new project and it worked just fine. What exactly is the crash you are getting?

Comment: I'm getting a BAD ACCESS, I suspect my action to be freed somewhere before it ends, due to the nested nature of the code, but not sure... I worked around by calling another runAction from outside the sprite1 runAction.

Comment: Did you ever add both objects to the layer or scene with a call to addChild? Also are you doing this in init or onEnter?

Comment: Yes all objects are added yet and I'm not doing this from init/onEnter, I'm doing it on a button tap event.

Comment: Show what that code actually looks like. Since the above in my answer works, it is obviously something to do with said button and/or setup.